# I want to reload table data every 1second with DataTables

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I would like to re-arrange the order of the tables once a second. 
But... I have no idea.
The default settings are as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
            "paging":   false,
            "info":     false,
            "searching" : false,
            "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]]
    });
});
```

In this state, how can I simply modify the order of the table so that it continues to be periodically reordered? The values in the table are processed by other JavaScript. That's why I just want to reorder every second in same method.

So, I made in this way. but that doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
   var refreshTable = $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
            "paging":   false,
            "info":     false,
            "searching" : false,
            "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]]
   });
   setInterval( refreshTable , 1000 );});
```

Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want is to *redraw* the table every second... (are you sure? that's pretty heavy use - much better to redraw just when the data changes... But that's for another post...)

You're almost there - just missing a [simple little API call](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()):

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var myTable = $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
            "paging":   false,
            "info":     false,
            "searching" : false,
            "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]]
    });
    setInterval(function() {
        myTable.rows().invalidate().draw(); 
    }, 1000 );
});
```

**UPDATE**

Depending on who changes your data, and how, you might have to invalidate dataTable's cache before you redraw; I've updated the code snippet above.

Note that if your other scripts change the data in the DOM table directly, and you loaded the data through JSON, you might have to force DataTables to use the DOM as your data source when you invalidate:

```
myTable.rows().invalidate('dom').draw();
```

(See the documentation on [invalidate](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().invalidate()))

Hope it helps!

Comment: There is no error... but not ordered with new data.

Comment: So you change the table data? What, exactly, are those other scripts doing?

Comment: At first... without DataTable script, all data has changed every 1S with other Ajax script .

Comment: And... I added DataTable script... So, The thing that DataTable have to do... is just ordering data field every 1S. but that's the problem. I don't know

Comment: Anyway, MacPrawn... really thank you. Concerning about this issue.

Comment: Ok - I've updated my answer... You might have to invalidate the internal cache first.

Comment: MacPrawn~~~~~~~ You are right!!! That works perfect!... I don't know how appreciate it... Really thank you again!

Comment: Sweet! Very happy I could help. I'd be very appreciative if you marked my answer as the right one too... ; )

Answer (score 0):

Please test this:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
 function refreshTable() {
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
        "paging":   false,
        "info":     false,
        "searching" : false,
        "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]]
});}
setInterval(refreshTable , 1000 );});
```

Comment: Hi~~~ Thank you for your effort... but error below. "DataTables warning:table id=dataTables-example - Cannot reinitialise dataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.ent/tn/3"

Comment: I did not knew you have problem with `DataTable`. I think the problem is about repeating the process, and mentioned the true way of using  `setInterval`. If you test this easy code: `var abc = alert("Hi");
        setInterval(abc, 1000);`  you will see that `setInterval` does not work in this way